# How to create a non-field instance-level variable on a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

If I understand well, `ClassVar` is a way of creating a class-variable on a dataclass, a variable which won't be considered as a field. So, for example:

```
@dataclass
class MyData:
    name: str
    age: int
    parent: ClassVar[Optional["MyData"]] = None

jake_data = MyData(name="Jake", age=34)

dataclasses.fields(jake_data) # This will output only two fields, as status is a ClassVar
```

But if I want to modify `parent` at the instance level after the instance's initialisation, it should not be a `ClassVar`, as [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) makes it clear that the `ClassVar` annotation should only be used for variables which are not replaced at instance level. And I don't want to declare `parent` as a field with a default value because then it would be... a dataclass field!

For the context: I use libraries that rely on the output of `dataclasses.fields`, that's why I want it to be a non-field variable.

Is there a pythonic and readable way to do that?

Comment: There are [init only varaibles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables), which don't seem to be what you want.  Dataclasses aren't really designed to have non-transient variables that aren't fields.  How would you be using the `status`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I've edited the question (replaced `status` by `parent`) so it is closer to the use I have. As you can see, I am using this variable as a reference. I will need to set it only once, but it needs to be after initialisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't annotate it, and define it in the `__post_init__`, so something like:

```
@dataclass
class MyData:
    name: str
    age: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.parent = None
        # whatever else
```